# Validation of integer in C++

Tags: c++, validation, integer

I am confused a little here. Why does the code give me an infinite loop when entering a letter?

```
do
{
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout << "Please Enter a Number: ";
    cin >> N;
} while (cin.fail());
```

Comment: Read the whole line into a string. Try to convert the string into an integer. If it's invalid or out of range, try again. Putting it in a separate function is also a good idea.

Comment: `cin.ignore` won't do anything, because `cin` is in a `fail` state.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow
Validation of integer in C++
[Validation of integer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77246651/validation-of-integer-in-c/77246995#77246995)

##### Call `cin.clear` before calling `cin.ignore`

After a failure, you have to clear `std::cin` before inputting or ignoring any characters in the input stream.

If `std::cin` is in a failed state, no characters can be input or ignored. Calling `std::cin.clear()` resets the input stream's `failbit` (along with its `eofbit` and `badbit`), after which `std::cin` is no longer in a failed state. Only then, will calls to `std::cin.ignore` have any effect.

In your case, you need to reverse the order of calls to `std::cin.ignore` and `std::cin.clear`:

```cpp
do
{
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();  // MUST CALL CLEAR BEFORE CALLING IGNORE.
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    cout << "Please Enter a Number: ";
    cin >> N;
} while (cin.fail());
```

##### Test `cin.fail()` after input, rather than before

In the comments below, @Remy Lebeau makes a good case for testing `cin.fail()` after getting input from `cin`, rather than before.

```cpp
for (;;)
{
    std::cout << "Please Enter a Number: ";
    if (std::cin >> N)
        break;
    std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

This is closer to how I would code this myself.

If, however, there is a *precondition* that `cin.fail()` returns `false`, established either implicitly or explicity before entering this loop, then the effect of this "improvement" is "nothing changed." Both the OP's code, and this version, behave the same.

That is why I say in the comments that I am fine with how the OP coded this, if that's the way he wants to do it.

##### Using a function for console input

In my own work, I use the technique described by @Some programmer dude in his comment above:

> Read the whole line into a string. Try to convert the string into an integer. If it's invalid or out of range, try again. Putting it in a separate function is also a good idea.

In addition, I allow the user to cancel an input operation by pressing Enter on a blank line. Otherwise, I keep looping, until the user gets it right.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627) includes source code for function `get_int`, a robust function that inputs an integer from `std::cin`. The answer also provides a detailed explantion of how it works.

`get_int` handles all the usual errors that can happen with `std::cin`, and loops until a valid integer is entered. It can also perform range checks on the numbers that are entered, rejecting any that are out of range.

At no time, does it call `cin.clear` or `cin.ignore`.

Here is its function prototype.

```cpp
    bool get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int& value,
        int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        bool const cancel_is_allowed = true,
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);
```

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to check `cin.fail()` *before* performing `cin >> N`. The read needs to be moved higher up in the loop, eg: `do { cout << "Please Enter a Number: "; if (cin >> N) { break; } cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); } while (true);`

Comment: Although I might do things differently, I am fine with checking `cin.fail()` before attempting input. That will cover you in case a previous input operation failed. Of course, if such a thing happened, and was not detected, you may already be in trouble.

Comment: You should always check for failure right after performing an I/O, don't wait until some later time.

Comment: If you validate when the I/O is performed, there wouldn't be an "existing error" to be validated/ignored later in the first place.

Comment: You say to test immediately after input. We agree. And, is that not exactly what `while(cin.fail())` does in the OP's code? Yes. It is.

Comment: BTW: If this code block is entered with `cin` already having failed, there is an argument to not allow further input at all: `if (std::cin.good()) do { ... } while (...)`. Effectively, that's how I handle it in my work. Yet, the OP, my answer, and your improved answer all allow an existing error to be ignored. We merrily call `cin.clear()` and pretend everything will be fine. So, let's add a precondition, and insist that users verify that `cin` is not in a failed state before this code block is entered.